# Android: how to take a <span> text without class attribute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

Hello i have some problem to take an html code and retrive, for exemple a phrase or a word to a string with Jsoup. The html part of the code where is the span (without the class) is this:

```
<table align="center" width="253">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align: center;">
     <span style=" font-weight: normal">
       Festival
     </span>
     <br>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to take the phrase/word with this code

```
private class ricerca extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String phrase;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                Document document =  Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                Elements research = document.select("span[style= font-weight: normal");
                phrase = research.attr("span");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        result.setText(phrase);
    }

}
```

, but in the EditText doesn't apper nothing....why? Where is my error? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the string "Festival" than you should use `phrase = research.text();`
You are also missing the closing bracket at the end of - `Elements research = document.select("span[style= font-weight: normal");`